# Azure App Service Plan D1 - 240 minutes used how?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

The Azure App Service Plan D1 says you get 240 minutes/day. Is that the first 240 minutes of every day? Or is this just usage? How does this work if an app service is set to "Always on"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that the first 240 minutes of every day? Or is this just usage?

In App Service Plan D1(Shared), it is just for the usage.

For example, when your website is responding to requests, it actives and you are "on the clock." When the site has been idle for a while, it will effectively go to sleep and you are "off the clock."

If your compute minute usage exceeds the quota (here it's 240 minutes), then Azure will return a 403 message to the browser and your site is unavailable until the quota resets for the next day.

> How does this work if an app service is set to "Always on"?

App Service Plan D1(Shared) does not support "Always on" feature.

Comment: What exactly constitutes being "idle for a while"? Is this 30 seconds? Is it 30 mins?

Answer (score 1):

That's 240 minutes of usage per day.  **Always On** is not supported on the D1 plan.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits

Comment: Thanks. And does that mean the 240 minutes is just usage? Not just the first 240 minutes of the day?

Comment: Well, if you start running it continually at midnight, that will effectively be for the first 240 minutes of the day ;-)

Comment: what does "start running it continually" mean? If it's not "always on" then it would only run when it's serving requests.

Answer (score 1):

The D1 is a Shared plan which is just recommended for test / develop environments but not for production.

And it only supports 240 CPU minutes (Usage) everyday) , You cannot enable Always On Free Tier plans such as F1 AND D1